# Sporadic "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" Error

Tags: ssh, redhat, rhel6

I have an RHEL 6.8 x86_64 server that has had a long running problem with the SSH server. It has openssh-5.3p1-118.1.el6_8.x86_64 installed. Every so many attempts to connect to SSH/SFTP, the server gives back the error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

It doesn't happen every time, so it is very hard to debug. When it does happen, even with more verbose logging, nothing shows up in the SSH logs about what happened. What I have noticed is that I have to restart sshd every few weeks or it quits working all together.

Can you offer any suggestions on how I could diagnose this issue and fix it?

---

Update (27-Aug-16): Here's the results of `ssh -vvv` on a failed connection:

```
timothys-MacBook-Pro:~ tbutler$ ssh -vvv tbutler@myserver
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserver [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tbutler/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried logging in again and received the same result. Finally on the third try, I was able to connect, which resulted in the debug information looking much the same, but then continuing with:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
```

Comment: Do you only have to restart `sshd` to resolve it?  I'm also wondering if there could be firewall (or fail2ban or similar) rules that may be interfering intermittently.

Comment: Every few weeks, yes. However, it does have issues at other times that are very intermittent -- sometimes just retrying a second or third time will resolve the issue.

Comment: Post the whole verbose log with `-vvv` switches of failed connection. The context matters. Also server logs might help. It might be only connection rate limit enforced by the server, because of various scans/log in attempts.

Comment: Thanks, @Jakuje. I've posted the verbose output above. When the connection fails, I don't see any reference to it in the server log. Do you think it could be that there are that many fake login attempts?

Comment: Certainly yes. How many of them do you have in time frame of, lets say 1 minute?